# SQL Exception : Too many database connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I try to connect to the database for a query, there is an exception occurred. 
"SQL Exception : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

```
public class DBConnection {
   public static java.sql.Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException    {

    Connection con = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");




    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmr";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";

    try {
        //            Establishing connection
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception : "+ ex);
    }


    if(con != null){
        System.out.println("****CONNECT TO THE DATABASE*****");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("####NOT CONNECT TO THE DATABASE");
    }
    return con;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should have searched for [that error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), it's  not **this** code.

Comment: There is a sort of rule of thumb to go by: if an object implements `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` interfaces in Java, it is most likely designed in a way that expects its `close()` method to be called at some point. `Connection` is exactly one of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using the local installation of MySQL db then use the below commands to check the how many connection are currently open.

```
mysql> show status like 'Conn%';
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
```

To get process list use:  `mysql> show processlist;`

You can kill the unnecessary connections.

If you are using a database server maintained by other party then get their help to check and kill the unnecessary connections. There is property in  mySQL server to specify the max number of connection allowed. You have increase it if necessary.

On Java side, i think after you done with database operation you should call `con.close` in finally block. Am not sure if you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks Sanket D..

Answer (score -2):

"Too many connections" error comes because server connected maximum  limit of connection which server can be donem so server can not connect to new client. for solve this problem you need to restart the database server.

Comment: "...for solve this problem you need to restart the database server"?! Don't give such advices to other people when you are not aware of the consequences of given action.